# php: how can i change Stored value into user friendly values !

Tags: php, mysql, user-interface, str-replace

the problem in short,

```
Field:ProfileItems = "action,Search,Work,Flow,pictures";

Mysql query = "SELECT ProfileItems FROM addUsers";
```

then I `explode` with `,` making array e.g.: `array('action','search',...etc)`

and create fields for `,`

### Result:

```
<form>
action : <input type=text name=action>
search : <input type=text name=search>
...etc
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

My problem is how can I replace names in the database with more user friendly ones (add description) to fields without using an `IF` statement??

```
//created asoc array with Key = search item and value = user friendly value
$prase = array("ABS" => "ABS (Anti lock braking System)"
         ,"DriverAirBag" => "Air bags");
$string= "ABS,DriverAirbag,GOGO,abs";

foreach($prase as $db=>$eu){
    echo "if $db will be $eu<br>";
    echo str_ireplace($eu,$db,$string);
}
echo $string;
```

Tried above but was an epic fail :D !.. can you please help me out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a map inside PHP is not an unreasonable approach, but you're doing the `str_ireplace()` backwards: it's `search, replace, subject`, so in your case `str_ireplace($db, $eu, $string);`

But just doing a `str_ireplace()` on a comma-separated list of strings is not ideal anyway. For one thing, imagine if after you did the substitution for `ABS` you then encountered another profile item that matched `lock` (which just so happens to appear in "Anti-lock braking system"). Oops. Now you've overwritten your earlier replacement!

How about something like this:

```
$prase = array("ABS" => "ABS (Anti lock braking System)"
         ,"DriverAirBag" => "Air bags");
$string= "ABS,DriverAirbag,GOGO,abs";
$fields = explode(',', $string);

foreach($fields as $field) {
    $friendly = $field;
    if (isset($phrase[$field]))
        $friendly = $phrase[$field];

    echo htmlspecialchars($friendly) . ': <input type="text" name="' . htmlspecialchars($field) . '" />
}
```

The key here is that you're handling each field separately. And you're never just doing a replacement; you're looking specifically for the keywords "ABS" or "DriverAirbag". If there's not an exact match, you don't have a human-friendly name for that item, and there's no point doing any replacement.

All this can be improved even further if you have the ability to change the database schema. Storing a comma-separated list is never desirable. You should have a table with a schema something like:

- field_id (e.g., "ABS")
- name (e.g., "Anti-lock Braking System")

And another table like:

- user_id (I'm inferring a little here from the name `addUsers` — whatever field/s you have in addUser now identifying the person)
- field_id (i.e., foreign key to the above `field` table)

Note that you may end up with many rows in this table for each person `(1, 'ABS'), (1, 'DriverAirbag')`

But then your query can become

```
SELECT field, name
FROM user_field
INNER JOIN field USING (field_id)
```

Now you get back one row for each field (no `explode` required!) and each row includes both the computer-friendly and human-friendly name.

Comment: well thank you very much :) as for db schema i realy wana change, but dont know better way to do it !,

my current app. (is a more or less survey app).
database fields:
ID,Question,Answer,Target,type
eg of data: 
Question:saftey options you require
Answer:ABS=ABS (Anti lock braking System),DriverAirBag=Air bags"
target:saftey
type=checkbox

Prepare:
so when i show question i hv to explode answers twice, then set type of display according to type(select,checkbox,text)

result:Question : (prepared answer).
any ideas to better design :) ?!